# All html styling is stripped in mails sent with HTML mail and SMTP Authentication

Tags: 7, theming, emails

I use the SMTP Authentication Support module in combination with the HTML Mail module. I have set it up according to this post ([https://www.drupal.org/node/1200142)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1200142).

After writing the new classes as instructed in the post above, the mails are sent successfully, but all the styling is stripped in the mail.

When I use only the HTML Mail class, and don't use the SMTP class, this does not happen. But then the emails dont get through to many recipients. I need to use the SMTP Authentication to get my emails delivered.

The check box  `Allow to send e-mails formatted as Html` is checked in the settings for SMTP Authentication Support module.

Also, I use the `htmlmail.tpl.php` template file in my theme, which works when SMTP Authentication class is not used.

Any ideas about this problem? Why is my template file ignored when using SMTP?